# How to order feeds by their latest item contained?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create "feeds" in SQL that contain "items", and when I am getting all the feeds (`SELECT * FROM Feeds`), I want to order them by when they were last updated (the last time an item was added to the feed). The "item" has a publish date column.

So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    F.FeedID,
    F.Title,
    F.Link,
    F.Language,
    F.Copyright,
    F.Subtitle,
    F.Author,
    F.Summary,
    F.OwnerName,
    F.OwnerEmail,
    F.ImageURL,
    F.Category
FROM Feeds F
LEFT JOIN Items I
    ON F.FeedID = I.FeedID
ORDER BY I.PublishDate DESC
```

Somehow I want to order the "items" joined on so that the most recent item is joined on with that feed. Is this possible? Or should I just add a "last updated" column to the "feeds" table?

Comment: Add the column - see Esoteric's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a last updated column of type DateTime, and set the value appropriately when inserting or updating rows, as your needs dictate. That is to say, set its value depending on whether you want the most recently updated item or the item which was most recently added (updated versus inserted), as they may differ. You can then order by this new column.

You cannot use order by on the data as shown to find the last modified item, as publish date is (almost certainly) the date the book was published, not the date the row was added to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Date created and date updated are very important things to track in a database.

A ERD (entity relationship diagram) shows how the database is laid out.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

The details of both tables will help in clearing up what you are trying to accomplish.